# How to easily disable Gmail signature on a per message basis

Tags: gmail, email-signature

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In Gmail, how can I have customized signatures based on the From: address?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/2384/in-gmail-how-can-i-have-customized-signatures-based-on-the-from-address)

I have Gmail set up to fetch also my work email account so I can have all my email in one app. I use a signature with my work emails, and Gmail auto-inserts this for me. But it places it into every message, even non-work messages. I end up manually deleting the work specific portion of the signature for every non-work message I compose.

Is there a way to have a different signature for each "from" address you use? Or a way to disable the signature on a per message basis (other than manual deletion)?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here is what I've done for signatures:

1. Disable the signature completely in
   your settings.
2. Turn on canned responses lab feature.
3. Set up a canned response for each signature
   you want to use.
4. Choose the
   appropriate signature each time you
   send an email.

The only downside is that you don't get an automatically inserted default.  Until Google improves the support for signatures, this is the most functional and least annoying that I could come up with.

Comment: Note that canned responses are now under "Settings" -> "Advanced" in the new Gmail interface. If you update the answer I'll delete this comment.

Answer (score 2):

**Corollary to the accepted @Brad Gardeber answer:**  If you never used the Canned Response lab, or any lab, before then these links may be helpful to use them:

- about.com text description: http://email.about.com/od/gmailtips/qt/et_templates.htm
- youTube video of the same directions, if you like watching better: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8snv5omwI2s

Both those links directions are for the *old compose/response view*.  If you use the new view, the only difference is that the Canned Response options are available from the arrow-dropdown in the lower-right corner next to the discard button.