# In Gmail, how can I have customized signatures based on the From: address?

Tags: gmail, email-signature

In Gmail, I have a number of accounts that I can choose to send from. (Old e-mail address, one used just for gaming, one for my blog, etc.)

How can I have a unique signature for each depending on which I choose?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Google *just* released Rich Text signatures, which also includes the ability to have a unique signature for each From address.

> Gmail also now supports a unique signature for each email address associated with your account. So, if you send mail using a [custom "From:" address](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=22370), you can use a different signature for that address. From the Settings page, you can edit the signature for each account by changing the email address that appears in the dropdown menu.

https://gmail.googleblog.com/2010/07/rich-text-signatures.html

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked at canned responses;

https://gmail.googleblog.com/2008/10/new-in-labs-canned-responses.html

These can be used along with filters.

Answer (score -1):

Check out [WiseStamp](http://www.wisestamp.com) extension for Firefox and Chrome.