# Multiple Signatures in Gmail

Tags: gmail

I would like to add multiple signatures as I have 2 of us that use Gmail. Is this possible? I have searched everywhere and cannot seem to find the answer.  Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: That depends. Are you using two different "from:" addresses, or just one?

Comment: If the former, then this should answer your question: [In Gmail, how can I have customized signatures based on the From: address?](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/2384/354)

Answer (score 0):

From what I could find as well not really. I have seen multiple places where a workaround exists such as using Canned Responses. You can reference the how-to [here](https://www.mail-signatures.com/articles/how-to-set-up-multiple-signatures-in-gmail/) . As Ale suggested as well if you need a different signature for each from address you can use the following [link](https://gmail.googleblog.com/2010/07/rich-text-signatures.html) to accomplish it.